# Notion API: Is there a way to get the number of child pages with a user mentioned in the "people" property?

Tags: notion-api

I'm trying to create some Notion API integrations to help my team forecast availability for staffing.

I am writing a function that should count all the times a particular user is mentioned in the `people` property of a database child page by using the `people` filter type.

Here's my code:

```js
async function getUserAssignmentCount(database, user) {
  const response = await notion.databases.query({
    database_id: database.id,
    filter: {
      "property": "People",
      "people": {
        "contains": user.id,
      },
    },
  });

  return Object.keys(response).length;
}
```

For a reason I don't quite understand, this function simply returns `4` for every single user. A quick look at [the API docs for the people filter property](https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-database-query#people-filter-condition) shows that you can't currently filter for `people` properties using the `people` filter…so…idk??

Can anyone think of a way to achieve this, either via something undocumented in the API or with some hacky way of getting all the user IDs from a database `people` property?

Thanks <3

Answer (score 2):

Well, that was anticlimactic. The API is still poorly documented but I found the way:

```js
async function getUserAssignmentCount(database, user) {
  // Returns an object with keys `object`, `results`, `next_cursor`, `has_more`
  const response = await notion.databases.query({
    database_id: database.id,
    filter: {
      "property": "People",
      "people": {
        "contains": user.id,
      },
    },
  }); 
  
  // Returns the length of the filter results
  return response.results.length;
}
```